Correct Syntax for a SAM template Customer Managed Policy
Consider the following reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-role
Under the header for Policies:
it reads:
"""Policies
Permission policies for this function. Policies will be appended to the function's default AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) execution role.
This property accepts a single value or list of values. Allowed values include:
AWS SAM policy templates.
The ARN of an AWS managed policy or customer managed policy.
The name of an AWS managed policy from the following list.
An inline IAM policy formatted in YAML as a map.
"""
Please give an example of a sam template function role which contains the "The ARN of a customer managed policy," which is also declared inside the same template.
I've gotten as far as something like:
Resources:
  AthenaAccessManagedPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub 'athena-access-${env}-${AWS::Region}-policy'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - athena:GetWorkGroup
              - athena:GetTableMetadata
              - athena:StartQueryExecution
              - athena:GetQueryResults
              - athena:GetDatabase
              - athena:GetDataCatalog
              - athena:ListQueryExecutions
              - athena:ListDatabases
              - athena:GetQueryExecution
              - athena:ListTableMetadata
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:athena:*:${AWS::AccountId}:datacatalog/AwsDataCatalog'
  FunctionMachineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'function-machine-${env}-${AWS::Region}-role'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service:
                - states.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - !Ref 'AthenaAccessManagedPolicy'
  FunctionMachine:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: FunctionMachine
      DefinitionUri: /path/to/file
      Role: !GetAtt 'FunctionMachineRole.Arn'

But this doesn't seem to work.
This is a simple example, I have 10's of machines, roles, and customer managed policies I'd like to implement, but a pattern that I can follow would be ideal.
